# Download images from server to host in flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, image, host, blobstore

i had uploaded my laravel project on hosting server, the images was stored in laravel/public folder then the generated url saved in my database like as: public/image.jpg,  how can I retrieve  the images in flutter by using online website url??

in flutter application :
main_url="http://mydomain.byethost7.com/api/";

```
FutureBuilder(
           future: downloadImage(url),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot  snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                  snapshot.hasData) {
                 return Container(
                    width: w,
                    height: h,
    child: Image.network(snapshot.data.toString(),fit: BoxFit.cover));
              }

             return Container();
            }
        )

Future<String> downloadImage(String url)async
{
  return await main_api_url + "getimage/$url";
}
```

in laravel api.php file is:

```
Route::get('getimage/{url}','App\Http\Controllers\Api\ImageController','get_image']);
```

```
in ImageController i have this function to return image as file:
public function get_image($url)
    {     
      ob_end_clean();

    return response()->file(public_path('storage/public/'.$url));


}
```

in laravel my ImageController class:

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{

public function save_images(Request $req)
{

if($req->hasFile($op['images']))
            {
              $images=$req->file($op['images']);
              foreach ($images as $image)
               {
                  $path=$image->store('public');
                  $img=new Image();
                  $img->url=$path;
                  $img->product_id=$product_id;
                  $img->title="";
                  $img->save();


          }

        }
}


}
```

in database images table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWZRN.png)

but in flutter i got this error:

```
Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:6637:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:6494:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodecWithSize (dart:ui/painting.dart:2291:60)
#3      PaintingBinding.instantiateImageCodecWithSize (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:182:15)
#4      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:153:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://murhafyildiz.byethost7.com/api/getimage/7zTKC23PVI5WTmGrbAIjnyQMFRMZEYUdzL9csuq9.png", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://murhafyildiz.byethost7.com/api/getimage/7zTKC23PVI5WTmGrbAIjnyQMFRMZEYUdzL9csuq9.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.